# Discord.py How to tranform a str to a specific type from discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to set the permission of the server, using that code a `wait ctx.guild.edit(verification_level=line)`, but I get that error `verification_level field must be of type VerificationLevel`. I presume the problem is the variable type. How can I transform any str to a specific type used by Discord.py?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`discord.py` Enums implement `__getitem__`, and attempt to lookup the supplied key in their internal map.  You can do

```
await ctx.guild.edit(verification_level=VerificationLevel[line])
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'VerificationLevel' is not defined

Comment: `VerificationLevel` is part of the `discord` module.  Include `from discord import VerificationLevel` in your imports